# Dog peeing in house when gone

Tags: dogs, behavior, toilet-training

I have an almost 3 year old beagle mix, I have had him since he was just a bit under a year old. He is house trained and used to never pee or poop in the floor. Now he's gotten to the point where he will pee in the floor while I'm gone.

He will hold it a good part of the day while I'm sleeping and I'll take him out as soon as I wake up, usually right before I go to work, but when I come home from work there's always pee on the floor.

Same thing if I go out anywhere, even if I'm only gone for like 30 minutes, I will come home to pee on the floor. He doesn't display any signs of separation anxiety, he doesn't whine when I leave, he's not bouncing off the walls when I get home, he greets me at the door with a wag and goes about his day.

What could be causing him to pee on the floor? I have cleaned and cleaned, but I can't get the smell of dog pee to go away now and I know my landlord is going to be furious.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the site. Is he desexed?

Comment: Yes, he was neutered when he was a puppy

Comment: I asked a question below, but also curious when his last physical was, or vet appointment was- and what was it for? Routine visit? Thanks, also any other residing health issues may help.

Comment: His last vet visit was the beginning of this year. it was a routine check up and to get his shots updated. He currently has an appointment this afternoon for an ear infection that he has developed.

Comment: Get him checked for a urinary tract infection.That should always be the first step when a pet starts to break their housetraining.

Comment: Can you confirm that the cleaner that you are using specifically has pet enzymes? If you do not clean with pet enzymes, no matter what you use or how well you scrub, dogs will keep going there. Also, some cleaners market themselves as for pet use but do not contain pet enzymes.

Answer (score 2):

I would first eliminate the medical aspect of this before anything else as the comments suggest.

Otherwise, I can suggest what a friend did when her dog starting peeing randomly in the house. She tried multiple things but what worked was to leave the TV on in the living room where the dog passed a lot of its time alone, left a radio on where the dog slept and also left a shirt of hers in the dog's bed.

The dog stopped peeing the next day.

Imagine she even left her laptop on the coffee table and skyped the dog at home to see what he's doing but that didn't work either (and resulted in a saliva-covered screen/keyboard) - might be worth a shot for you.

I can't imagine her electric bill though having the TV and radio run 9-10+ hours a day.

Good luck!

Comment: I leave the radio on for my pup when I'm at work and my electric bill did not noticeably increase from before I did this.  Unless you're using a large sound system (which is unnecessary anyway) a single radio shouldn't draw too much power.

Comment: Modern TV's and radios hardly use any electricity at all. There probably wasn't even a noticeable shift in her bills.